# GData and OAuth in Python: Unable to convert request token to access token

Tags: python, oauth, request, token, gdata

I am trying to implement a button on a web-based dashboard that allows a user to export the current data to a Google Spreadsheet using OAuth and GData API. Currently, I can get the user to a login/grant access page, but if I add the line to convert the request token to an access token, I receive:

"RequestError: Unable to upgrade OAuth request token to access token: 400, parameter_absent
oauth_parameters_absent:oauth_token"

I am following the instructions for OAuth 2 on this page:

https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/oauth

and have read both PyDocs for the Google APIs and found no details on this issue:

http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.docs.client.html#DocsClient

(Won't let me post a this hyperlink but other Pydoc is same URL but replace the piece after pydocs/ with gdata.gauth.html#ClientLoginToken)

This is the code that works:

```
def createDocsClient(self, oauth_callback_url):
  docsClient = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source='RiskOps-QualityDashboard')
  request_token = docsClient.GetOAuthToken(SCOPES, oauth_callback_url, CONSUMER_KEY,  consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
  domain = None
  auth_url = request_token.generate_authorization_url(google_apps_domain=domain)
  self.redirect(str(auth_url))
  request_token = gdata.gauth.AuthorizeRequestToken(request_token, self.request.uri
```

With the above code, I get to a grant access page and if you click the grant access page, you get a 404 error because it doesn't know where to go after (as expected), but the page has the proper URL displayed listing an oauth_verifier and oauth_token. The "AuthorizeRequestToken" line is supposed to use that URL to authorize the token so up to this line, everything seems to work.

When I add the following line right after the code above, I get the "RequestError" I wrote about:

```
access_token = docsClient.GetAccessToken(request_token)
```

I've tried different combinations of nesting the calls within each other, using the AeSave and AeLoad (as the instructions mention might be needed but I'm not sure if my case calls for it) and many other random and unsuccessful ideas and nothing is really giving me a good idea of what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Would really appreciate and help or any ideas anyone has.(If you can't tell, I'm fairly inexperienced when it comes to real-world code (as opposed to academic code). Thanks so much.